# How to include MultipartEntityBuilder in the project

Tags: android, apache, gradle, android-volley, multipart

I need to use MultipartEntityBuilder in order to send MultipartRequest using Volley.

I managed to import other org.apache.http.entity.mime libraries like content.FileBody, but for MultipartEntityBuilder I need to compile an external library using gradle.

**I tried :**

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'

compile (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpmime' , version: '4.3.5') {
        exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
    }
```

**and also:**

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4'
```

but I got this run time error:

```
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use repackaged version: [httpclientandroidlib](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) instead. Note you will need to update your `import`s to not refer `org.apache...` but `ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib....` instead